# AttributeError: module 'plotly.tools' has no attribute 'set_credentials_file'

Tags: python, plotly

I am following an introduction tutorial for plotly and I am facing a problem, using Jupyter.

This is the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import cufflinks as cf

import chart_studio.plotly as py

import plotly.tools as tls
import plotly.graph_objs as go

tls.set_credentials_file(username = "xxx", api_key = "yyyy")
```

And the error I am getting.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 1
----> 1 tls.set_credentials_file(username = "xxxx", api_key = "yyy")

AttributeError: module 'plotly.tools' has no attribute 'set_credentials_file'
```

All the other questions I am seeing on SO are from some years ago and I am afraid the documentation of the package is updated.

Can someone help?

Comment: I think the method you are using is deprecated. Have you seen [this document](https://dash.plotly.com/authentication)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was mentioned by @Sotos in the comment, the *set_credentials_file* file is no longer available in *plotly.tools*.

You should use the *chart_studio* instead: https://pypi.org/project/chart-studio/ and it should work for you:

```
import chart_studio.tools as tls

tls.set_credentials_file(username='xxx', api_key='yyyy')
```

Also have a look at the current Getting Started doc: https://plotly.com/python/getting-started-with-chart-studio/.